# How to add right side legend to US highcharts map that shows eastern states names?

Tags: highcharts

I am able to generate the US map, but whenever I try to add the custom map used in this JS fiddle, my code breaks with an error that says 'feature is not defined.' I want to generate the right side legend that names the small states:

http://jsfiddle.net/q5zhbmr3/

Here is a working example of my code: https://codepen.io/MartinLawrence/pen/yLYLWLz?editors=0010

If anyone has any suggestions on how to apply that code for my specific situation, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

```
var data = [
    ['us-ma', 0],
    ['us-wa', 1],
    ['us-ca', 2],
    ['us-or', 3],
    ['us-wi', 4],
    ['us-me', 5],
    ['us-mi', 6],
    ['us-nv', 7],
    ['us-nm', 8],
    ['us-co', 9],
    ['us-wy', 10],
    ['us-ks', 11],
    ['us-ne', 12],
    ['us-ok', 13],
    ['us-mo', 14],
    ['us-il', 15],
    ['us-in', 16],
    ['us-vt', 17],
    ['us-ar', 18],
    ['us-tx', 19],
    ['us-ri', 20],
    ['us-al', 21],
    ['us-ms', 22],
    ['us-nc', 23],
    ['us-va', 24],
    ['us-ia', 25],
    ['us-md', 26],
    ['us-de', 27],
    ['us-pa', 28],
    ['us-nj', 29],
    ['us-ny', 30],
    ['us-id', 31],
    ['us-sd', 32],
    ['us-ct', 33],
    ['us-nh', 34],
    ['us-ky', 35],
    ['us-oh', 36],
    ['us-tn', 37],
    ['us-wv', 38],
    ['us-dc', 39],
    ['us-la', 40],
    ['us-fl', 41],
    ['us-ga', 42],
    ['us-sc', 43],
    ['us-mn', 44],
    ['us-mt', 45],
    ['us-nd', 46],
    ['us-az', 47],
    ['us-ut', 48],
    ['us-hi', 49],
    ['us-ak', 50],
    ['undefined', 51],
    ['undefined', 52],
    ['undefined', 53],
    ['undefined', 54],
    ['undefined', 55],
    ['undefined', 56],
    ['undefined', 57],
    ['undefined', 58],
    ['undefined', 59],
    ['undefined', 60]
  ],
  mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/custom/us-small']);

$.each(mapData, function() {
  var path = this.path,
    copy = {
      path: path
    };

  // This point has a square legend to the right
  if (path[1] === 9727) {

    // Identify the box
    Highcharts.seriesTypes.map.prototype.getBox.call({}, [copy]);

    // Place the center of the data label in the center of the point legend box
    this.middleX = ((path[1] + path[4]) / 2 - copy._minX) / (copy._maxX - copy._minX);
    this.middleY = ((path[2] + path[7]) / 2 - copy._minY) / (copy._maxY - copy._minY);
  }

  // Tag it for joining
  this.ucName = this.name.toUpperCase();
});

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/custom/us-small.js">United States of America, small</a>'
  },
  mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
  },
  colorAxis: {
    min: 0
  },
  series: [{
    data: data,
    mapData: mapData,
    name: 'Random data',
    states: {
      hover: {
        color: '#BADA55'
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        return this.point.properties['hc-a2'];
      }
    }
  }, {
    name: 'Separators',
    type: 'mapline',
    data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/custom/us-small'], 'mapline'),
    color: 'silver',
    showInLegend: false,
    enableMouseTracking: false
  }]
});
```

Current code I am using:

```
function addElement(parentId, elementTag, elementId, className, html, width, height) {
    // Adds an element to the document
    var p = document.getElementById(parentId);
    var newElement = document.createElement(elementTag);
    newElement.setAttribute('id', elementId);
    newElement.setAttribute('class', className);
    newElement.innerHTML = html;

    if (width != undefined || height != undefined) {
        var style = "";
        if (width != undefined && width != "") {
            style += "width:" + width + "px;"
        }

        if (height != undefined && width != height) {
            style += "height:" + height + "px;"
        }

        newElement.setAttribute('style', style);
    }

    p.appendChild(newElement);
}

var lang = 1;
var categoryLabel = 'Category';

(function() {
    var htmlTemplate = "<div id='vis-BusinessConcentration'></div>";

    var width = "-1";

    var height = "-1";

    addElement("BusinessConcentration", "div", "vis", "visualization-container", htmlTemplate, width, height);

    if ("BusinessConcentration" == "RiskRatingBarometerIndustry" || "BusinessConcentration" == "RiskRatingBarometerSector" || "BusinessConcentration" == "BusinessConcentration") {
        setTimeout(createChart(), 1000);
    } else {
        createChart();
    }

    function createChart() {

        if (typeof window['Highcharts'] !== 'undefined') {



            var optionsNew = {
                "series": [{
                    "allAreas": false,
                    "data": [{
                        "name": "Alabama",
                        "value": 1.2
                    }, {
                        "name": "Alaska",
                        "value": 0.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Arizona",
                        "value": 1.2
                    }, {
                        "name": "Arkansas",
                        "value": 0.7
                    }, {
                        "name": "California",
                        "value": 12.0
                    }, {
                        "name": "Colorado",
                        "value": 1.2
                    }, {
                        "name": "Connecticut",
                        "value": 1.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Delaware",
                        "value": 0.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "District of Columbia",
                        "value": 0.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Florida",
                        "value": 5.5
                    }, {
                        "name": "Georgia",
                        "value": 2.7
                    }, {
                        "name": "Hawaii",
                        "value": 0.5
                    }, {
                        "name": "Idaho",
                        "value": 0.4
                    }, {
                        "name": "Illinois",
                        "value": 4.2
                    }, {
                        "name": "Indiana",
                        "value": 1.5
                    }, {
                        "name": "Iowa",
                        "value": 0.9
                    }, {
                        "name": "Kansas",
                        "value": 0.8
                    }, {
                        "name": "Kentucky",
                        "value": 1.2
                    }, {
                        "name": "Louisiana",
                        "value": 1.4
                    }, {
                        "name": "Maine",
                        "value": 0.6
                    }, {
                        "name": "Maryland",
                        "value": 1.9
                    }, {
                        "name": "Massachusetts",
                        "value": 2.1
                    }, {
                        "name": "Michigan",
                        "value": 2.8
                    }, {
                        "name": "Minnesota",
                        "value": 1.4
                    }, {
                        "name": "Mississippi",
                        "value": 0.7
                    }, {
                        "name": "Missouri",
                        "value": 1.6
                    }, {
                        "name": "Montana",
                        "value": 0.4
                    }, {
                        "name": "Nebraska",
                        "value": 0.6
                    }, {
                        "name": "Nevada",
                        "value": 0.5
                    }, {
                        "name": "New Hampshire",
                        "value": 0.4
                    }, {
                        "name": "New Jersey",
                        "value": 3.9
                    }, {
                        "name": "New Mexico",
                        "value": 0.4
                    }, {
                        "name": "New York",
                        "value": 16.0
                    }, {
                        "name": "North Carolina",
                        "value": 2.9
                    }, {
                        "name": "North Dakota",
                        "value": 0.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Ohio",
                        "value": 3.1
                    }, {
                        "name": "Oklahoma",
                        "value": 0.9
                    }, {
                        "name": "Oregon",
                        "value": 1.1
                    }, {
                        "name": "Pennsylvania",
                        "value": 4.1
                    }, {
                        "name": "Rhode Island",
                        "value": 0.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "South Carolina",
                        "value": 1.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "South Dakota",
                        "value": 0.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Tennessee",
                        "value": 1.6
                    }, {
                        "name": "Texas",
                        "value": 5.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Utah",
                        "value": 0.6
                    }, {
                        "name": "Vermont",
                        "value": 0.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Virginia",
                        "value": 2.3
                    }, {
                        "name": "Washington",
                        "value": 2.4
                    }, {
                        "name": "West Virginia",
                        "value": 0.5
                    }, {
                        "name": "Wisconsin",
                        "value": 1.6
                    }, {
                        "name": "Wyoming",
                        "value": 0.1
                    }],
                    "dataLabels": "1px contrast"
                }],
                "colorAxis": {
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 16.0,
                    "tickLength": 5,
                    "tickInterval": 5,
                    "tickAmount": 4
                }
            };

            var options = {
                chart: {
                    map: 'countries/us/us-all',
                    width: 800,
                    height: 600,
                    marginTop: 40,
                },
                exporting: {
                    buttons: {
                        contextButton: {
                            menuItems: ['viewFullscreen', 'printChart', 'separator', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadJPEG', 'downloadPDF', 'downloadSVG']
                        }
                    },
                    enabled: true
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'United States',
                    align: 'center',
                    style: {
                        color: '#333333',
                        fontSize: '16px',
                        lineHeight: '22px',
                        fontWeight: '500',
                        fontFamily: 'Noto Sans, Roboto',
                    },
                    enabled: true,
                },
                legend: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Percentage of Establishments (%)',
                        style: {
                            color: '#333333',
                            fontSize: '14px',
                            lineHeight: '18px',
                            fontWeight: 'normal',
                        },
                    },
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
                    floating: true,
                    layout: 'horizontal',
                    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                    y: 0,
                    align: 'right',
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },

                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 1,
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    borderColor: '#AAA',
                    borderRadius: 10,
                    style: {
                        padding: 0,
                    },
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() {
                        //console.log(this);
                        return '<div class="map-tooltip">' +
                            '<span style="color:' + this.point.color + '">\u25CF</span><br>' +
                            '<div class="label">' + this.point.name + '<br>' + this.point.value + '%' + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
                    },
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    map: {
                        borderColor: 'white',
                        borderWidth: 0.2,
                        joinBy: ['name', 'name'],
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
                                color: '#002F65',
                                fontSize: '14px',
                                fontWeight: 'normal',
                                textOutline: '1px #FFFFFF'
                            },
                            formatter: function() {
                                var max = 6,
                                    color = this.point.value < max ? 'black' : 'white';
                                //console.log(this);  

                                if (this.point.name == 'Norfolk Island' || this.point.name == 'Yukon' || this.point.name == 'Nunavut' || this.point.name == undefined || this.point.name == 'Bounty Islands' || this.point.name == 'The Snares') {

                                } else if (this.series.mapTitle == 'Australia') {
                                    if (this.point['hc-a2'] == 'CT') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">ACT</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.point['hc-a2'] == 'NS') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px; ">NSW</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.point['hc-a2'] == 'QL') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">QLD</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.point['hc-a2'] == 'TS') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">TAS</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.point['hc-a2'] == 'VI') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">VIC</span><br>';
                                    } else {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">' + this.point['hc-a2'] + '</span><br>';
                                    }
                                } else if (this.series.mapMap.Dublin) {
                                    if (this.key == 'Mid-East') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">ME</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'South-West') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px; ">SW</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'South-East') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">SE</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'Midland') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">MD</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'Mid-West') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">MW</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'Border') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">BO</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'West') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">W</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'Dublin') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">DU</span><br>';
                                    } else {
                                        return '';
                                    }
                                } else if (this.series.mapMap.Scotland) {
                                    if (this.key == 'Scotland') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;">SCT</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'Wales') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold;font-size:12px; ">WAL</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'East Midlands') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">EMD</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'South West') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">SW</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'Northern Ireland') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">NIR</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'Yorkshire') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">YKS</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'North East') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">NE</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'North West') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">NW</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'South East') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">SE</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'West Midlands') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">WMD</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'East of England') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">‎UKH</span><br>';
                                    } else if (this.key == 'London') {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font-weight:bold; font-size:12px; ">‎LDN</span><br>';
                                    } else {
                                        return '';
                                    }
                                } else if (this.series.mapTitle == 'United States of America' || this.series.mapTitle == 'Canada' || this.series.mapTitle == 'China' || this.series.mapTitle == 'New Zealand' || this.series.mapTitle == 'Germany') {
                                    try {
                                        return '<span style="color: black; font - weight:bold; font - size:12px; ">' + this.point.properties['hc-a2'] + '</span><br>';
                                    } catch (err) {
                                        if (this.point.name == 'Tibet') {
                                            return '<span style="color: black; font - weight:bold; font - size:12px; ">TB</span><br>';
                                        }
                                        if (this.point.name == 'Inner Mongolia') {
                                            return '<span style="color: black; font - weight:bold; font - size:12px; ">NM</span><br>';
                                        } else {
                                            console.log('not rendering', this.point.name);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    return '<span style="color: black; font - weight:bold; font - size:12px; ">' + this.point.name + '</span><br>';
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            };

            if (options.yAxis && options.yAxis.length === 1) options.yAxis = options.yAxis[0];
            if (options.xAxis && options.xAxis.length === 1) options.xAxis = options.xAxis[0];
            if (options.zAxis && options.zAxis.length === 1) options.zAxis = options.zAxis[0];

            Highcharts.merge(true, options, optionsNew);

            if (options && (options.lang || options.global)) {

                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    global: options.global || {},
                    lang: options.lang || {}
                });

            }
            if (1 == 2) {
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    lang: {
                        decimalPoint: ',',
                        thousandsSep: '.'
                    }
                });
            }

            var chart = new Highcharts.mapChart('vis-BusinessConcentration', options);

            if (chart) {
                if (chart.options.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.length == 3) {
                    chart.options.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems[2].text = 'View Data'.toUpperCase();
                }
            }



        }
    }

}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working demo with your simplified code: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/54kc3epq/

All that needed to be done is:

1. Paste custom map script in HTML
2. Copy mapData variable and dataLabels correction:

   ```
      mapData = Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['countries/us/custom/us-small']);

       $.each(mapData, function() {
           var path = this.path,
               copy = {
                  path: path
               };

       // This point has a square legend to the right
       if (path[1] === 9727) {

       // Identify the box
       Highcharts.seriesTypes.map.prototype.getBox.call({}, [copy]);

       // Place the center of the data label in the center of the point legend box
       this.middleX = ((path[1] + path[4]) / 2 - copy._minX) / (copy._maxX - copy._minX);
       this.middleY = ((path[2] + path[7]) / 2 - copy._minY) / (copy._maxY - copy._minY);
        }

       // Tag it for joining
       this.ucName = this.name.toUpperCase();
   });
   ```
3. Define mapData in series config.

Next time when you will need help please simplified the code from unnecessary parts, not related to the issue, as much as you can. That will facilitate a way to find a solution or even will clarify a situation which makes able to find it by yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Looks like I wasn't referencing the 
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/us/custom/us-small.js"></script> so that's what was causing unable to find feature error. Thank you for your detailed breakdown!